# How should I add Crypto++ 8.80 library to NS3 3.31 ? The OS is Ubuntu 20.04. My main aim to test TLS 1.3 cipher suites with wireless sensor network

Tags: cryptography, crypto++, ns-3, waf

How should I add Crypto++ 8.80 library to NS3 3.31 ?  The OS is Ubuntu 20.04. My main aim to test TLS 1.3 cipher suites with wireless sensor network.

Here are some specific pointers:

- The NS3 installation is working properly. I am able to run the ns3 scripts that are provided with the examples & tutorials folders.
- Also NetAnim 3.108 is also working properly.
- I have added the source code of Crypto++ 8.80 lib to contrib folder as contrib/cryptopp.
- I had downloaded the source code from https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/releases/tag/CRYPTOPP_8_8_0.

Please tell me what should my next steps be. Also if there is no way please tell me alternatives as well.

So here is what I have tried:

Firstly I have put the source code in inside /home/hex/ns-allinone-3.31/ns-3.31/contrib/cryptopp.

**Here are the files in the above mentioned folder:**

```
3way.cpp                  dh.cpp                   lubyrack.h         serpentp.h
3way.h                    dh.h                     luc.cpp            sha1_armv4.h
adhoc.cpp.proto           dll.cpp                  luc.h              sha1_armv4.S
adler32.cpp               dll.h                    mars.cpp           sha256_armv4.h
adler32.h                 dlltest.cpp              mars.h             sha256_armv4.S
adv_simd.h                dlltest.vcxproj          marss.cpp          sha3.cpp
aes_armv4.h               dlltest.vcxproj.filters  md2.cpp            sha3.h
aes_armv4.S               dmac.h                   md2.h              sha512_armv4.h
aes.h                     donna_32.cpp             md4.cpp            sha512_armv4.S
algebra.cpp               donna_32.h               md4.h              shacal2.cpp
algebra.h                 donna_64.cpp             md5.cpp            shacal2.h
algparam.cpp              donna_64.h               md5.h              shacal2_simd.cpp
algparam.h                donna.h                  mdc.h              sha.cpp
allocate.cpp              donna_sse.cpp            mersenne.h         sha.h
allocate.h                donna_sse.h              misc.cpp           shake.cpp
arc4.cpp                  Doxyfile                 misc.h             shake.h
arc4.h                    drbg.h                   modarith.h         sharkbox.cpp
argnames.h                dsa.cpp                  modes.cpp          shark.cpp
aria.cpp                  dsa.h                    modes.h            shark.h
aria.h                    eax.cpp                  modexppc.h         sha_simd.cpp
aria_simd.cpp             eax.h                    mqueue.cpp         simeck.cpp
ariatab.cpp               ec2n.cpp                 mqueue.h           simeck.h
arm_simd.h                ec2n.h                   mqv.cpp            simon128_simd.cpp
asn.cpp                   eccrypto.cpp             mqv.h              simon.cpp
asn.h                     eccrypto.h               naclite.h          simon.h
authenc.cpp               ecp.cpp                  nbtheory.cpp       simple.cpp
authenc.h                 ecp.h                    nbtheory.h         simple.h
base32.cpp                ecpoint.h                neon_simd.cpp      siphash.h
base32.h                  elgamal.cpp              nr.h               skipjack.cpp
base64.cpp                elgamal.h                oaep.cpp           skipjack.h
base64.h                  emsa2.cpp                oaep.h             sm3.cpp
basecode.cpp              emsa2.h                  oids.h             sm3.h
basecode.h                eprecomp.cpp             osrng.cpp          sm4.cpp
bds10.zip                 eprecomp.h               osrng.h            sm4.h
bench1.cpp                esign.cpp                ossig.h            sm4_simd.cpp
bench2.cpp                esign.h                  padlkrng.cpp       smartptr.h
bench3.cpp                factory.h                padlkrng.h         sosemanuk.cpp
bench.h                   fhmqv.h                  panama.cpp         sosemanuk.h
bfinit.cpp                Filelist.txt             panama.h           speck128_simd.cpp
blake2b_simd.cpp          files.cpp                pch.cpp            speck.cpp
blake2.cpp                files.h                  pch.h              speck.h
blake2.h                  filters.cpp              pkcspad.cpp        square.cpp
blake2s_simd.cpp          filters.h                pkcspad.h          square.h
blowfish.cpp              fips140.cpp              poly1305.cpp       squaretb.cpp
blowfish.h                fips140.h                poly1305.h         sse_simd.cpp
blumshub.cpp              fipsalgt.cpp             polynomi.cpp       stdcpp.h
blumshub.h                fipstest.cpp             polynomi.h         strciphr.cpp
camellia.cpp              fltrimpl.h               power7_ppc.cpp     strciphr.h
camellia.h                gcm.cpp                  power8_ppc.cpp     tea.cpp
cast.cpp                  gcm.h                    power9_ppc.cpp     tea.h
cast.h                    gcm_simd.cpp             ppc_simd.cpp       test.cpp
casts.cpp                 gf2_32.cpp               ppc_simd.h         TestData
cbcmac.cpp                gf2_32.h                 pssr.cpp           TestPrograms
cbcmac.h                  gf256.cpp                pssr.h             TestScripts
ccm.cpp                   gf256.h                  pubkey.cpp         TestVectors
ccm.h                     gf2n.cpp                 pubkey.h           tftables.cpp
chacha_avx.cpp            gf2n.h                   pwdbased.h         threefish.cpp
chacha.cpp                gf2n_simd.cpp            queue.cpp          threefish.h
chacha.h                  gfpcrypt.cpp             queue.h            tiger.cpp
chachapoly.cpp            gfpcrypt.h               rabbit.cpp         tiger.h
chachapoly.h              GNUmakefile              rabbit.h           tigertab.cpp
chacha_simd.cpp           GNUmakefile-cross        rabin.cpp          trap.h
cham.cpp                  gost.cpp                 rabin.h            trunhash.h
cham.h                    gost.h                   randpool.cpp       ttmac.cpp
cham_simd.cpp             gzip.cpp                 randpool.h         ttmac.h
channels.cpp              gzip.h                   rc2.cpp            tweetnacl.cpp
channels.h                hashfwd.h                rc2.h              tweetnacl.h
cmac.cpp                  hc128.cpp                rc5.cpp            twofish.cpp
cmac.h                    hc128.h                  rc5.h              twofish.h
config_align.h            hc256.cpp                rc6.cpp            validat0.cpp
config_asm.h              hc256.h                  rc6.h              validat10.cpp
config_cpu.h              hex.cpp                  rdrand.asm         validat1.cpp
config_cxx.h              hex.h                    rdrand.cpp         validat2.cpp
config_dll.h              hight.cpp                rdrand.h           validat3.cpp
config.h                  hight.h                  rdseed.asm         validat4.cpp
config_int.h              History.txt              rdtables.cpp       validat5.cpp
config_misc.h             hkdf.h                   Readme.txt         validat6.cpp
config_ns.h               hmac.cpp                 regtest1.cpp       validat7.cpp
config_os.h               hmac.h                   regtest2.cpp       validat8.cpp
config_ver.h              hmqv.h                   regtest3.cpp       validat9.cpp
cpu.cpp                   hrtimer.cpp              regtest4.cpp       validate.h
cpu.h                     hrtimer.h                resource.h         vc60.zip
crc.cpp                   ida.cpp                  rijndael.cpp       vmac.cpp
crc.h                     ida.h                    rijndael.h         vmac.h
crc_simd.cpp              idea.cpp                 rijndael_simd.cpp  vs2005.zip
cryptdll.vcxproj          idea.h                   ripemd.cpp         wake.cpp
cryptdll.vcxproj.filters  Install.txt              ripemd.h           wake.h
cryptest.nmake            integer.cpp              rng.cpp            whrlpool.cpp
cryptest.sln              integer.h                rng.h              whrlpool.h
cryptest.vcxproj          iterhash.cpp             rsa.cpp            words.h
cryptest.vcxproj.filters  iterhash.h               rsa.h              x64dll.asm
cryptest.vcxproj.user     kalyna.cpp               rw.cpp             x64masm.asm
cryptlib.cpp              kalyna.h                 rw.h               xed25519.cpp
cryptlib.h                kalynatab.cpp            safer.cpp          xed25519.h
cryptlib.vcxproj          keccak_core.cpp          safer.h            xtr.cpp
cryptlib.vcxproj.filters  keccak.cpp               salsa.cpp          xtrcrypt.cpp
cryptopp.mapfile          keccak.h                 salsa.h            xtrcrypt.h
cryptopp.rc               keccak_simd.cpp          scrypt.cpp         xtr.h
cryptopp.supp             lea.cpp                  scrypt.h           xts.cpp
darn.cpp                  lea.h                    seal.cpp           xts.h
darn.h                    lea_simd.cpp             seal.h             zdeflate.cpp
datatest.cpp              License.txt              secblockfwd.h      zdeflate.h
default.cpp               lsh256_avx.cpp           secblock.h         zinflate.cpp
default.h                 lsh256.cpp               seckey.h           zinflate.h
des.cpp                   lsh256_sse.cpp           Security.md        zlib.cpp
des.h                     lsh512_avx.cpp           seed.cpp           zlib.h
dessp.cpp                 lsh512.cpp               seed.h
dh2.cpp                   lsh512_sse.cpp           serpent.cpp
dh2.h                     lsh.h                    serpent.h
```

Next I have added the following lines inside wscript:

**This is the code I have added.**

```
 # Add Crypto++ module
    # New Code
    bld = conf.bld
    # New Code

    # New Code
    bld.recurse('contrib/cryptopp') 
    bld.env.prepend_value('INCLUDES', ['contrib/cryptopp'])
    # New Code
```

The file is located at /home/hex/ns-allinone-3.31/ns-3.31/src/wscript.

***Here is the code:***

https://pastebin.com/DnLN5iE6

Next I have added another piece of code under # New Code:

```
    # New Code
    # Add Crypto++ module
    module = bld.create_ns3_module('CryptoPP', ['cryptlib'])
    module.source = ['cryptlib.cpp']
    # New Code
```

I have added the above code inside the file wscript located at /home/hex/ns-allinone-3.31/ns-3.31/contrib/wscript.

***Here is the code:***

https://pastebin.com/kWqkxiFE

Here is the error I am getting after running the command:

```
root@hex:/home/hex/ns-allinone-3.31/ns-3.31# ./waf configure


Setting top to                           : /home/hex/ns-allinone-3.31/ns-3.31 
Setting out to                           : /home/hex/ns-allinone-3.31/ns-3.31/build 
Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : /usr/bin/gcc 
Checking for cc version                  : 9.4.0 
Checking for 'g++' (C++ compiler)        : /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking for compilation flag -Wl,--soname=foo support : ok 
Checking for compilation flag -std=c++11 support       : ok 
Checking boost includes                                : headers not found, please provide a --boost-includes argument (see help) 
Checking boost includes                                : headers not found, please provide a --boost-includes argument (see help) 
Checking for program 'python'                          : /usr/bin/python3 
Checking for python version >= 2.3                     : 3.8.10 
python-config                                          : /usr/bin/python3-config 
Asking python-config for pyembed '--cflags --libs --ldflags --embed' flags : yes 
Testing pyembed configuration                                              : yes 
Asking python-config for pyext '--cflags --libs --ldflags' flags           : yes 
Testing pyext configuration                                                : yes 
Checking for compilation flag -fvisibility=hidden support                  : ok 
Checking for compilation flag -Wno-array-bounds support                    : ok 
Checking for pybindgen location                                            : ../pybindgen-0.21.0 (guessed) 
Checking for python module 'pybindgen'                                     : 0.21.0 
Checking for pybindgen version                                             : 0.21.0 
Checking for code snippet                                                  : yes 
Checking for types uint64_t and unsigned long equivalence                  : no 
Checking for code snippet                                                  : no 
Checking for types uint64_t and unsigned long long equivalence             : yes 
Checking for the apidefs that can be used for Python bindings              : gcc-LP64 
Checking for internal GCC cxxabi                                           : complete 
Checking for python module 'pygccxml'                                      : not found 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hex/ns-allinone-3.31/ns-3.31/.waf3-2.0.18-ff4ae9f5cc05353d3dc3aeff8854ae69/waflib/Scripting.py", line 119, in waf_entry_point
    run_commands()
  File "/home/hex/ns-allinone-3.31/ns-3.31/.waf3-2.0.18-ff4ae9f5cc05353d3dc3aeff8854ae69/waflib/Scripting.py", line 182, in run_commands
    ctx=run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/home/hex/ns-allinone-3.31/ns-3.31/.waf3-2.0.18-ff4ae9f5cc05353d3dc3aeff8854ae69/waflib/Scripting.py", line 173, in run_command
    ctx.execute()
  File "/home/hex/ns-allinone-3.31/ns-3.31/.waf3-2.0.18-ff4ae9f5cc05353d3dc3aeff8854ae69/waflib/Configure.py", line 85, in execute
    super(ConfigurationContext,self).execute()
  File "/home/hex/ns-allinone-3.31/ns-3.31/.waf3-2.0.18-ff4ae9f5cc05353d3dc3aeff8854ae69/waflib/Context.py", line 85, in execute
    self.recurse([os.path.dirname(g_module.root_path)])
  File "/home/hex/ns-allinone-3.31/ns-3.31/.waf3-2.0.18-ff4ae9f5cc05353d3dc3aeff8854ae69/waflib/Context.py", line 126, in recurse
    user_function(self)
  File "/home/hex/ns-allinone-3.31/ns-3.31/wscript", line 499, in configure
    conf.recurse('src')
  File "/home/hex/ns-allinone-3.31/ns-3.31/.waf3-2.0.18-ff4ae9f5cc05353d3dc3aeff8854ae69/waflib/Context.py", line 126, in recurse
    user_function(self)
  File "/home/hex/ns-allinone-3.31/ns-3.31/src/wscript", line 57, in configure
    bld = conf.bld
AttributeError: 'ConfigurationContext' object has no attribute 'bld'
```

How should I rectify this error ?

Answer (score 0):

As waf said, there's no "bld" attribute attached to ConfigurationContext "conf".

To correct this specific error, remove `bld = conf.bld` and use the conf object to recurse into your new module:

```py
conf.recurse('contrib/cryptopp') 
conf.env.prepend_value('INCLUDES', ['contrib/cryptopp'])
```

Note that I'm no ns3 expert.

Comment: Still getting errors...  I had modified the wrong wscript file. The correct wscript file to modify was located in ns-3.31 folder & additionally I have created & modified the file in the cryptopp folder where the source code for crypto++ lib is located. The cryptopp wscript is complete but I still dont know how to correctly modify the ns-3.31/wscript file. Please tell. Here are the errors I am getting  after running commands ./waf distclean & ./waf configure.

Link: https://pastebin.com/7LjRAvyG

Comment: You use "opt" in configure method, where you should use "conf", the parameter of the configure method.